# Make a python web API run only one at a time?

Tags: python

I'd like to make a python Azure Function App (web API) to process a queue of tasks. I already setup some trigger that call this API whenever a task is inserted into the queue. As this API will process all of the current tasks in the queue, I would like to prevent the API to execute if there is other execution of this API at the time, to avoid processing conflicts.

I think of using a database locking mechanism but it doesn't look so elegant. Is there any singleton design pattern that can used in Python Azure function App for this purpose? Thanks.

Comment: That's really a cripplingly bad design for a web API.  You should instead change your processing so that it can allow many requests at once.  Most databases are multiuser safe.

Comment: What sort of queue is it? Many of them will already have a mechanism to automatically add a worker when there are items in the queue and shut the worker down when the queue is empty; one keyword to search for may be "auto-scaling".

Comment: (Auto-scaling is usually used for multiple workers, but there's nothing stopping you configuring it so the maximum number of workers is 1.)

Comment: @sabik: I am using Azure Storage Queue. I have some systems that posts one or several tasks at some random time during the day. I already have a function (Web API) that can process all the task in the queue. I can periodically can this function, for example every 30 minutes, but I would like to make it better by monitoring the event of new task inserted and call the function on the event of the 1st task insertion of the series. This way, the delay time will be reduced. Also as there is some limitation in the task processing, I only want to do it sequentially.

Comment: @sabik: setting the maximum number of worker threads can be a good advice. I will try and let you know.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure Storage Queue, but there should be recipes out there for scaling the worker pool up and down depending on the queue size; you should be able to adapt one of those to scale the "worker pool" to 1 worker when there are any items, and down to 0 afterwards

Comment: An alternative would be to modify your Azure Function App to process a single item, then configure it to be triggered for each item out of the Azure Storage Queue separately; that would be another common pattern of how to process queues. That would require the function to work correctly even if two copies are running at the same time, which may or may not be easy, depending on what it does. It would also be a lot more scalable, which may or may not be important in your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this problem using Azure Durable function. There are 3 types of functions in an Azure Durable Function app: Orchestration Client function, Orchestrator function, Activity functions. I just need to add some checking steps in the Orchestration Client function like the following example:

```
# This function an HTTP starter function for Durable Functions.
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

def is_finished(runtime_status : df.models.OrchestrationRuntimeStatus):
    result = False
    if runtime_status is None or \
       runtime_status in [df.OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Canceled,
                          df.OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Completed,
                          df.OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Failed,
                          df.OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Terminated]:
        result = True
    return result

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:

    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    # general azure function url : http://<APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FUNCTION_NAME>
    # function.json -> "route": "orchestrators/{functionName}/{instanceId}"

    orchestrator_instance_id = req.route_params['instanceId']
    function_name = req.route_params['functionName']

    INVENSYNC_ORCHESTRATOR_INSTANCE_ID = '117610EF-BC37-4E31-BFA4-205EBB3CC54E' # just select any key

    if orchestrator_instance_id == INVENSYNC_ORCHESTRATOR_INSTANCE_ID:
    
        existing_instance_status = await client.get_status(orchestrator_instance_id)

        logging.info(f"InventorySyncHttpStart() - existing_instance_status = '{existing_instance_status}'.")
        if existing_instance_status is None or \
           is_finished(existing_instance_status.runtime_status):

            logging.info(f"InventorySyncHttpStart() - existing_instance_status.runtime_status = '{existing_instance_status.runtime_status}'.")
            orchestrator_instance_id = await client.start_new(function_name, orchestrator_instance_id)

            logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{orchestrator_instance_id}'.")

            result = client.create_check_status_response(req, orchestrator_instance_id)
        else:
            result = func.HttpResponse(status_code=409, body=f"An instance with ID '{orchestrator_instance_id}' already exists")

    else:
        result = func.HttpResponse(status_code=406, body=f"Invalid Instance ID '{orchestrator_instance_id}' in URL")

    return result
```